# Route [product/products] not defined. (View:

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to get products related to that category from index page but it shows error, whole of these things are working fine at admin side but not at user side,

index.blade.php:

```
     @foreach($categories as $category)
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-4 m-l-r-auto">
                <!-- block1 -->

                <div class="block1 hov-img-zoom pos-relative m-b-30">
                    <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/backend_images/category_images/{{ $category->category_image }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 370px; height: 448px;" />

                    <div class="block1-wrapbtn w-size2">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="{{ route('product/products', $category->id) }}" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
                            {{ ucwords($category->category_name) }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

routes:

```
  Route::get('/product/{id}','ProductController@products');
```

route:list

paste.ofcode.org/Yw3CU2MXdCQXpxh9H3vKYh

Comment: what is this `<a href="{{ route('product/products', $category->id) }}"` wants to do?

Comment: @codeformoney this link is in categories button to go on products,,, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this is to define your route with a **name** like this:

```
Route ::get('/product/{id}','ProductController@products')->name('product.products');
```

Then specify your link like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('product.products', $category->id) }}" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
    {{ ucwords($category->category_name) }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<a href="{{ route('product/products', $category->id) }}" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
  {{ ucwords($category->category_name) }}
</a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.product.show', $category->id) }}" class="flex-c-m size2 m-text2 bg3 hov1 trans-0-4">
  {{ ucwords($category->category_name) }}
</a>
```

Comment: it takes me to the admin products page m working at user side

Comment: i think you wrap your route in admin. Did you use in your route **prefix** to admin?